# Have an ad space repeat every 10 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to put an adsense square (250x250) ad every ten posts in my posts list.
I tried adding this code to my index.php, inside of the posts div:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
  <?php if ($count == 11) : ?>
       Ad code is here
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
   <?php else : ?>
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It showed up correctly, but all the format of the posts changed for some reason.
Plus, this code only puts an ad after the tenth post, and it doesn't automatically repeat it after the twentieth, etc.
This is not actually really important, I could just repeat the numbers.

Comment: Modulus operator `if (($count % 10) == 0)`

Comment: there is a limit to how many adsense ads you can put on one page

Comment: Too much `<?php` for my taste..

Comment: `if($count%10==0)` == `if (($count % 10) == 0)` <= `?`

Comment: @Fred - yes.... I only added the extra brackets to make it clearer; though using spaces does make it more readable

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you Mark, I was only curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    //////////////////////
   <?php  if($count%10==0){  echo "</br></br></br>"; }   ?>
    ///////////////////

      <?php if ($count == 11) : ?>
           Ad code is here
              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
       <?php else : ?>
              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it works if i put anything instead of </br></br></br> , except for the ad code. if i put that wordpress tells me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on this line <?php  if($count%10==0){  echo "</br></br></br>"; }   ?>

Comment: @user2839612 change all `</br></br></br>` to `<br><br><br>` or `<br/><br/><br/>` - `</br>` is invalid and will cause errors.

Comment: i deleted thet and put the code of the ad, but it gives me that error